# How generate OAuth for azure vm

Tags: oauth, grafana

I installed Grafana on my Azure virtual machine. Now I want to set OAuth. 
In `defaults.ini`  I set the

```
name = my app
enabled = true
allow_sign_up = true
client_id = with my id
client_secret = with my client_secret 
scopes = openid email name
auth_url = 
token_url = 
api_url =
team_ids =
allowed_organizations =
```

And this not work.  Can anyone have some idea where I wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do not edit defaults.ini!
Use the following link to create or locate grafana.ini or custom.ini depending on your OS:
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/configuration/

I would recommend that you copy the block of code for the OAuth provider you want to use to grafana.ini/custom.ini and then edit it to suit your need.

You may have to edit the URL under the [server] settings to allow for the correct redirect when using external OAuth